# UIPickerView crashing when switching segemented control

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have four NSDictionaries that I would like to use to populate a pickerview depending on a segemented control.
With the code I have, the first segmented control/pickerview works fine but when I switch to the second segment the picker view only loads part of the second dictionary, that is it loads the same number of rows as it counted in the first dictionary. When I change the segmented control to the third or fourth segment it simply crashes with a sigabrt error indicating that it cannot index item43 when only 27 exist. This I suspect stems from a UItextfield population based on the upickerview row and object. I think the problem is with the way I have the data source and delegate set up.

```
#pragma mark -

#pragma mark UIPickerViewDelegate

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

 if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
  return [robskeys objectAtIndex:row];

 }
    if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
    {
        return [esabskeys objectAtIndex:row];
    }

 if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 2)
    {
        return [lebskeys objectAtIndex:row];
    }

 else if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 3)
    {
        return [sbskeys objectAtIndex:row];
    }


    return @"Unknown title";
}

#pragma mark -

#pragma mark UIPickerViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
        return robskeys.count;
    }

 if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 1)
    {
        return esabskeys.count;
    }

 if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 2)
    {
        return lebskeys.count;
    }

 else if ([wine selectedSegmentIndex] == 3)
    {
        return sbskeys.count;
    }


    return 1;
}

#pragma mark -
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thank you

UPDATE

Using the following when the segmentedcontrol is changed works. Does anyone see any problems in alloc, init, release the same picker view in viewDidLoad and in this IBAction. As you may have guessed the UItextfield winespec calls the coPicker not a keypad.

```
-(IBAction)ValueChanged:(id)sender {

    [winespec resignFirstResponder]; 

    UIPickerView *coPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    coPicker.tag = kCountryPickerTag;
    coPicker.delegate = self;
    coPicker.dataSource = self;
    [coPicker setShowsSelectionIndicator:YES];
    winespec.inputView = countryPicker;
    [winespec becomeFirstResponder];
    [coPicker release];

}
```

Comment: What code you are executing when you select a segment?

Comment: My guess is that, the **selectedSegmentIndex** value is getting reset somewhere.

Comment: selectedSegementIndex does not get reset anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you reloading the UIPickerView when you switch the data source? (The `reloadAllComponents` method should do the trick.)

Irrespective, the problem is that an "out of index" row is being selected, so you'll probably also need to use the UIPickerView's `selectedRowInComponent` method to select a "safe" row (the first for example) when you switch the data source.

**UPDATE**

In essence, when you (effectively) change the current data source via the segmented control you need to set the selectedRowInComponent to zero and call reloadAllComponents on your UIPickerView. That *should sort* it all out. As such you could put this within the action you use to respond to the segmented control changes.

Comment: @middaparka, I was hoping you wouldn't mind elaborating a little, when I tried reloadAllComponents for the longest dictionary it did not work, where should I put it and bearing in mind I am using didSelectRow to populate textfields how would I use selectedRowinComponent?

Comment: @middaparka- I am alloc init and releasing my UIPickerview in view did load as I animate it in and out depending on what text fields are entered so I am having trouble using [pickerView reloadAllComponents]

Comment: @Mattog1456 - Think you'll have to create an instance variable for it. :-)